# Send notification to specific email from column M only when value 1 in column L is chosen

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, email-notifications

I would like for my sheet to send a notification to the chosen mail in column M but only when value 1 is chosen in column L.

Sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wLd5mXAKQ7pWfo5_ZOSkbtvORfFcnAkg17TSZgN73jM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Ark1')return;
  if(e.range.columnStart=12 && e.value==1) {
    var subject="Whatever";
    var body="Whatever";
    GmailApp.sendEmail(e.range.offset(0,1).getValue(), subject, body)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you, but it says: "TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined" (linje 2, fil "SendMail").

Comment: You cannot run this type of function without a event object.  So I test them live by generating my own onEdit events.